# Getting 404 - File or directory not found when downloading a file

Tags: iis, download

I have hosted a web API which written in laravel on the IIS server. There is one "versionUpgrate" API where the app asks the server to send the link to an apk file to download if there is any version is out.
"
But when I execute the below URL in the browser, I am getting "404 - File or directory not found". I am expecting the file should get downloaded here.

> https://xxxx.xxxx/apk/beta_4_22_2.apk

Don't know what is blocking it here?

--------------EDIT --------------------
I believe laravel is not blocking it because this apk folder exists in the public folder. So URL is accessible.

Comment: Post your route and controller

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add the type to IIS MIME Types.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Selection "MIME Type" feature
3. Add...
4. type Extension ".apk" and MIME type "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
5. OK

Comment: It fixed the same issue I experienced so this answer should be accepted!